# The relationship between CDFs of two random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

Suppose that for random variable $X$, we have $Pr(X>b)>p$ where *b* and *p* are real numbers and $0 <= p<= 1$. Now suppose that for random variable *Y*, we have $Y>aX+cX^2$. Can we conclude the following and why?

$$Pr(Y>ab+cb^2)>p$$

Answer (score 0):

Without some conditions on $a$, $b$, and $c$, or on $X$ and $Y$, no. For example, take $a=1$, $b=-2$, $c=1$. Let $X=0$ and $Y=1$. Then $\mathbb P(X>b)=1$ but $\mathbb P(Y>ab+cb^2)=0$.

Comment: Thanks. What conditions should I consider?